# Linear combination with an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, orthonormal

Using $W = $ {$(x, y) | x, y ∈ R)$} Let $u = (1,3)$ and $v = (2, 1)$ defined by the inner product

$<u, v> = 2v_1u_1 - v_1u_2 - v_2u_1 + v_2u_2$

Find an orthonormal basis and express the vector $w = (1,1)$ as a linear combination with the obtained orthonormal basis.

As the vectors are orthogonal by the definition and equaling $0$, I normalised the vectors with the definition to obtain:

$u = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 65}, \frac{3}{\sqrt 65}\right)$ and $v = \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}\right)$

Assuming this is correct, as it may not be, then normally a linear combination would be formed by

$(1, 1) = c_1\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 65}, \frac{3}{\sqrt 65}\right) + c_2\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}\right)$

How do you apply the definition to the linear combination? Anything I try seems awfully messy. Again, perhaps my calculations were wrong but I'm not sure how.

Comment: $u$ and $v$ are already orthogonal wrt your inner product, so you need only to normalize them. When do that the components of $w$ wrt the normalized $\hat u$ and $\hat v$ are simply $\langle \hat u,w \rangle$ and $\langle \hat v,w \rangle$ respectively. That is $w = \langle \hat u,w \rangle \hat u + \langle \hat v,w \rangle \hat v$

Answer (score 1):

I can't see where you did get $\;\sqrt{65}\;$ for  $\;u\;$ :

$$\begin{cases}\left\|u\right\|=\sqrt{2\cdot1\cdot1-1\cdot3-3\cdot1+3\cdot3}=\sqrt5\\{}\\
\left\|v\right\|=\sqrt{2\cdot2\cdot2-2\cdot1-1\cdot2+1\cdot1}=\sqrt5\end{cases}\,\implies$$

$$ w_1:=\frac u{\left\|=\right\|}=\frac1{\sqrt5}(1,3)\,,\;\;w_2:=\frac v{\left\|v\right\|}=\frac1{\sqrt5}(2,1)$$

And now: since we have already an **orthonormal** basis, expressing *any* vector as a linear combination of it is pretty simple:

$$(1,1)=\left\langle (1,1),\,w_1\right\rangle\,w_1 +\langle (1,1),\,w_2\rangle w_2$$

where we used $\;\langle,\rangle\;$ to denote the inner product defined by your function

Comment: I thought the numbers for the normalisation process had to be squared so that it is the square root of $2 - 3^2 - 3^2 + 9^2$ which is how I got 65. Are you saying the definition negates the squaring function?

Comment: Ok, so Gaussian elimination is not required for finding linear combinations with orthonormal bases?

Comment: @DuncanK3 I don't understand what "squaring" are you talking about...Isn't what I wrote clear?

Comment: Yes what you wrote is great, thanks! I just thought finding the norm involved squaring the components before taking the square root.